# AutoMapper 8.0 ConstructUsing breaking change

Tags: c#, automapper

I use AutoMapper in my code and I have a generic wrapper that initializes the mapper. The code runs since long without any problems. After upgrading to AutoMapper 8 my custom converters are ignored. The responsible code for setting the converters is the following:

```
new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
   cfg.CreateMap(mySource, myTarget).ConstructUsing(myConverter);
```

This piece of code does not build with AutoMapper 8, because I have to use expressions. There is even an [upgrade guid](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html) provided, but I cant manage to get it running again.

I just expected to convert it to

```
new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
   cfg.CreateMap(mySource, myTarget).ConstructUsing(expr => myConverter);
```

but the converter is ignored.

Comment: cfg.CreateMap<mySource, myTarget>().ConvertUsing(new myConverter());

Comment: or cfg.CreateMap<mySource, mySource>().ConvertUsing<myConverter>();

Comment: @MohamedElrashid the docu does not suggest to convert ConstructUsing to a ConvertUsing, but to use the new syntax

Comment: see [ AutoMapper v8.0.0 Custom Type Converters documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/v8.0.0/Custom-type-converters.html)

Comment: @MohamedElrashid Thanks, but I think that even when the link you provided is called "AutoMapper v8" it refers to the old syntax (v7). The mentioned "void ConvertUsing(Func<TSource, TDestination> mappingFunction);" does not exist in version 8 anymore and is replaced by expression and for me it does not work anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved a similar issue by extracting the myConverter method into a separate class that inherits from ITypeConverter:

```
public class MyConverter : ITypeConverter<MySourceType, MyDestinationType>
{
    public MyDestinationType Convert(MySourceType source, MyDestinationType destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // Conversion logic here
    }
}
```

You can then replace the mapping config with the following:

```
cfg.CreateMap(mySource, myTarget).ConvertUsing<MyConverter>();
```

or

```
cfg.CreateMap<MySourceType, MyDestinationType>().ConvertUsing<MyConverter>();
```

Comment: For me this turned out to be a mismatching version of  AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection. (Automapper 10 vs extension version 8) ended up not instantiating the custom TypeConverter. 2 days later of empirical nightmare, downgraded to extension version 5.0.1). Working.